# select dataframes from a list based on maximum column value

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list x2 having two data frames, x and x1. Both have 4 columns: n,m,l and k. I want to select the data frame that has maximum last value for column k.

In the below example, I would like data frame 2nd to be selected because the last value in column K is greater than last value in column K for data frame 1.

```
x <- data.frame(n = c(2, 13, 5),m = c(2, 23, 6),l = c(2, 33, 7),k = c(2, 43, 8))
x1 <- data.frame((n = c(2, 3, 15),m = c(2, 3, 16),l = c(2, 3, 17),k = c(2, 3, 18))
x2<-list(x,x1)
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service.  Please post your attempt to answer this question and ask a specific relevant question.

Comment: @polka - I am new to R and hence not able to visualize how the coding would go.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23628/312334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lapply`, loop through the list of `x2` and get the last value of `k` column of that data frame. Using `which.max`, find the index which has the maximum of the previous `lapply` command and extract that dataframe from `x2`

Note: This code does not account for ties in the last value of k column.

```
x2[which.max(lapply(x2, function(x) tail(x$k, 1)))]

# [[1]]
#    n  m  l  k
# 1  2  2  2  2
# 2  3  3  3  3
# 3 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: It is not uncommon that answers that only involve code without any explanation are flagged as low quality.  I may be helpful for future readers to add a bit of text to explain how your code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x$k[length(x$k)] >= x1$k[length(x1$k)]) x else x1
```

an if statement where
`x$k[length(x$k)]` - gets the last element from column k of matrix x

```
   n  m  l  k
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3 15 16 17 18
```

Comment: @Imo seriously? do you think both answers are of poor quality or just mine? both are given in the same format and you have a problem with my answer.  my code is simple  if  statement with references to the compared values, almost self explanatory, if one needs more explanation then for sure to the answer using lapply function which is much less intuitive.

Comment: Note that you could also use `tail(x$k, 1)` in place of `x$k[length(x$k)]`. Maybe this is more readable, there's probably not a speed improvement.